# Differential equation / Separable

Tags: differential

I've been given the following ODE and have to solve for the general solution: $$ \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = y\cot x $$

I've looked at the solution, and it does the following:

$$ \int \frac{1}{y} \ dy = \int \cot x \ dx $$ $$ \ln y = \ln|\sin x| + c $$ 
$$\ln y = \ln|\sin x| + \ln c $$ $$ \ln y = \ln |c\sin x| $$ $$ y = c\sin x$$

I don't quite understand how they were able to convert $c$ into $\ln c $. Since $c$ is just a constant, it can very well be negative and the $\ln -ve$ is undefined.

I also don't understand why they were able to remove the absolute value sign?

Comment: You are correct. But $c$ can be replaced by $\ln k$ where $k$ is some other constant. And then you can name $k$ to be $c$. And this new $c$ is not the same as old $c$. This is done often.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we have:

$$\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=\ln\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|+\text{C}$$

Now, raising each term to $e$:

$$\exp\left(\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|\right)=\exp\left(\ln\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|+\text{C}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=\exp\left(\ln\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|\right)\cdot\exp\left(\text{C}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=\text{C}\cdot\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|$$

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common thing that we do. The thing is, we take the constant term itself as $\ln c$ and not $c$. Yes, this can lead to problems. To be on the safe side, you can take the constant terms to be $\pm \ln c$ which would give you the result as $y = c \sin x$ or $y = \frac{\sin x}{c}$. You can now just say that the solution is $y = k \sin x$ where $k$ is another constant term. Hence this doesn't cause any contradiction with writing the result as $y = c \sin x$ as $c$ is basically just a constant.

The only value that $k$ can't take in $y = k\sin x$ is $0$, which is of course true.

Answer (score 2):

When integration constants appear, their value remains undefined until you bring an extra condition. Until then, silently replacing the constant by a function of itself is harmless.

Like for instance

$$\log y=\log x+c$$ is often transformed into

$$y=cx$$

instead of

$$y=e^cx.$$

Comment: But it would be nice to write " $\ln d$ with $c=\ln d$ " instead so that everything would be clear, especially when knowing that the reader or student is just starting to study differential equations.

Comment: @BernardMassé: the point is precisely that the notation $c$ actually stands for "a constant" and it is accepted practice to reuse $c$ at will. Would be sad to lose this convenience, not nice.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\ln |y|=\ln|\sin{x}|+c$$
We can do this differently by exponentiating both sides instead:
$$e^{\ln |y|}=e^{\ln|\sin{x}|+c}$$
$$|y|=e^{\ln|\sin{x}|}\cdot e^c$$
$$|y|=|\sin{x}|\cdot e^c$$
Now, note that $e^c$ is an **arbitrary constant**. Therefore, we can substitute $k=e^c$:
$$|y|=k\cdot |\sin{x}|$$
Which explains why they "converted" from $\ln{c}$ to $c$, so that the result looks nicer.

Comment: yes, yes, very sexy indeed]

Comment: @sddjsdsajsjddjsd Did you understand why we may omit the absolute values in the last step?

Comment: @Pythagoricus $e^c$ > 0 for all values of c, so $k|sin x|$ will just be positive.

Comment: but since $\sin x > 0$ shouldn't it just be $y = k|\sin x|$ instead of $ y = k\sin x $ @Pythagoricus

Comment: @sddjsdsajsjddjsd You got it, it's tricky! But there is a reason we omit the absolute value. (Hint: $y = y(x)$ is necessarily differentible).

Comment: @sddjsdsajsjddjsd I'll give it away: The solution of a differential equation is taken over some open interval. We write $y=y(x),$ $x \in (a,b)$. In this case all we know is that $y(x)=k |\sin x|$, but where is $x$ from? Is it from $\mathbb{R}$? No, because $| \sin x |$ (the absolute value) is not differentible at $\sin x=0$. We must therefore exclude all the solutions of $\sin x = 0$, to do this we restrain $x$ in an interval between solutions of $\sin x = 0$. This way, $\sin x$ is either everywhere positive, or everywhere negative; thus we omit the absolute value!

Answer (score 1):

$\ln:\mathbb{R}_+^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a **bijective** function which means $$\forall y\in\mathbb{R}, \exists!\ x\in\mathbb{R}_+^*, y=\ln(x)  $$
So, by changing the $c$ to $\ln(c)$, the solution skips some simple steps which are: $$\exists k\in\mathbb{R}_+^*,\ c=\ln(k) $$ 
since $k$ is a constant we can rename it and can call it $c$.

Then, we have 'the new' $c\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$, so it can be included under the absolute value sign.

Comment: r u serious? -_-

Comment: is there any unclear step ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll address only the arbitrary constant here.

> I don't quite understand how they were able to convert $c$ into $\ln c $

Yes, it's true that $c$ could be negative.  But the $c$ in $\ln|\sin x| + c$ and  the $c$ in $\ln c$ are not actually the same $c$.  This is a fairly standard borderline abuse of notation in math.  Generally we use $c$ (or capital $C$) to represent arbitrary constants of integration, even when those arbitrary constants change form, so to speak.

A more pedantic approach would be to explain as follows:

---

$$\ln y = \ln |\sin x| + c$$
At this point we would like to remove the natural logs.  So, since $c$ is some arbitrary real number and since the natural log function is surjective onto the real numbers, then there must be some other (and positive) constant $c_2$ such  that $\ln (c_2) = c$.  Then we have
$$ \ln y = \ln|\sin x| + \ln(c_2).$$
Well, $c_2$ itself is just an arbitrary constant ("arbitrary" subject to the restriction that it must be positive), so let's just keep calling it $c$ so we don't get everything muddled with different constant names.  Therefore
$$ \ln y = \ln|\sin x| + \ln c.$$

---

In short, you may see solutions that always use $c$ to represent arbitrary constants, even if they are different arbitrary constants along the way.  **But the only constant we really care about is the one in the solution we obtain at the end.**  That's pretty much how we justify calling all arbitrary constants $c$ or $C$.  So in this problem, the only arbitrary constant we care about is the $c$ in $y = c \sin x$.